# beforeShowDay call a day twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

how can i prevent that the function beforeShowDay called a day to times? The jquery datepicker has two months.

```
30.01.2013 -> month side jan
31.01.2013 -> month side jan
01.02.2013 -> month side jan (last invisible day / placehoder)
02.02.2013 -> month side jan (last invisible day / placehoder)
03.02.2013 -> month side jan (last invisible day / placehoder)
----------------------------    
28.01.2013 -> month side feb (first invisible day / placehoder)
29.01.2013 -> month side feb (first invisible day / placehoder)
30.01.2013 -> month side feb (first invisible day / placehoder)
31.01.2013 -> month side feb (first invisible day / placehoder)
01.02.2013 -> month side feb
01.02.2013 -> month side feb
02.02.2013 -> month side feb
02.02.2013 -> month side feb
03.02.2013 -> month side feb
03.02.2013 -> month side feb
04.02.2013 -> month side feb
04.02.2013 -> month side feb
```

[image: Picture Example]

with beforeShowDay i count days and if some days called twice, the result is not right... how can i prevent the double calls of days?

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#other-months) jquery ui example:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        numberOfMonths: 2
    });
});
```